# Induced emf across the rim and the spokes

Tags: electromagnetism

Taka a standard spinning bicycle wheel with its spokes and place it in a magnetic field that is parallel with the axle. I know that if the spokes were not made of metal but some insulating rods there would be an emf and a corresponding current induced in the rim.

My question is what happens when the spokes are made of some conducting metal, will there be an emf induced across the spokes and what will the current be in the rim and spokes?

Comment: Please state your question more clearly, for example adding a drawing of wheel and B since 0ne point the center is always on one potential, the answer is probably yes

Comment: Just use Lorentz force on the spikes, and you see what happens.  How would there be one with only the rim ?